# Angular2 Routerlink: add query parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How can I add query parameters to `routerLink`?

```
@RouteConfig {
   {path: '/search',   name: 'Search', component: SearchCmp}
}
```

Let' say I want to route to `/search?q=asdf`,

```
<a [routerLink]= " [ '/Search' , {q= 'asdf'}] ">Link 1</a>
```

this resolves to `/search` .

Is there a way to add query parameters without using:

```
this.router.navigate( ['Search', { q: 'asdf'}]);
```

or

```
<a href="/search?a=asdf"> Link 2 </a>
```

?

Comment: Yea, this is same question and answer as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188060/send-string-value-to-component-on-url-navigation-in-angular-2/35188464#35188464

Comment: no it's not. i this question is about query parameters and not about route paramters

Comment: Please clarify. Do you want a generic way to add url params or are you looking for an Angular way?

Comment: im looking for an angular way. <a href="/search?a=asdf">Link></a> would trigger a page reload

Comment: Why do you need query parameters?
You are handling the routes in Angular not queries.
Your routes determine the queries so that means you need route parameters...?

Comment: you should use routeParams instead of query and oll you have power of angular or is there any specific reason to use `query parameters`

Comment: ok let me rephrase it: lets pretend i need to route to /search?q='asdf' for some reason. when using this.router.navigate( ['Search', { q: 'asdf'}])  every parameter not consumed by a route path goes in the query string. So the resolving path is /search?q='asdf'. i need to know if there's a smiliar behaviour when using routerLink

Comment: You may need query params to be able to have a sharable URL that will trigger the page's functionality

Answer (score 110, accepted):

If u need something as `/search?q=asdf` than you can simply use:

```ts
@RouteConfig {
   {path: '/search',   name: 'Search', component: SearchCmp}
}

//And to generate router Links use:

<a [routerLink]="['/Search']" [queryParams]="{q:'asdf'}"></a>
```

This will generate the href tag as `<a href="/search"` but on clicking the anchor tag will lead you to url `/search?q=asdf`. [queryParams] will let you add the query params with "?", otherwise they will be appended by ";". You can get this parameter in your `SearchCmp` using:

```ts
constructor(private _routeParams: RouteParams) {
   var queryParam = this._routeParams.get('q');
}
```

Comment: oh yes, that's it. thanks man! any chance to generate the href tag as /search?q="asdf" ?

Comment: This does not answer the original question.  This does: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39016381/1480995

Comment: As @MichaelOryl says, this not answer the question and produce curious URL like "search;q=asdf"

Answer (score 98):

OP (Original Poster) asked how to add **query parameters** via router link, not a **router parameters** as @SaUrAbH MaUrYa answered.

To add query parameters you need to use `[queryParams]` binding:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/users']" [queryParams]="{ page: 1 }">next page</a>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The `[queryParams]` property binding is helpful when generating links dynamically, e.g. within a `*ngFor` loop:

```
<li *ngFor="let a of accounts">
   <a [routerLink]="['/account']" [queryParams]="{ id: a.Id }">{{a.Name}}</a>
</li>
```

I couldn't get this to work with the other construct as suggested by SaUrAbH MaUrYa (unless I needed a hardcoded query string value)

Comment: how to pass page number dynamically 
I try to use [queryParams]="{ page: {{myPageVariable}} }" and it is not working

Comment: [queryParams]="{ page: myPageVariable }"