# how to pass route params in [routerLink] angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-routerlink

I'm trying to create an application with angular 2,And Want pass params to tag a in [routerLink],i want craete a link like this :

```
<a href="/auth/signup?cell=1654654654"></a>
```

i dont know how to pass `cell` in template...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Routerlink: add query paramters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226245/angular2-routerlink-add-query-paramters)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your are going to use **angula2 beta** then you have to send parameter like this while doing routing.

```
<a [routerLink]="['signup',{cell:cellValue}]">Routing with parameter</a>                        
<input type='text' [(ngModel)]='cellValue'>
```

and than in the receiving side than you have to get parameter via  using `RouteParams`.

nut if You are going to use angular2 RC than you have to  use **`RouteSegment`** instead of using `RouteParams` in angular2 RC. like this :-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Routes, RouteSegment, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'about-item',
  template: `<h3>About Item Id: {{id}}</h3>`,
  Directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

class AboutItemComponent { 

  id: any;

  constructor(routeSegment: RouteSegment) {
    this.id = routeSegment.getParam('id');    
  }
}

@Component({

    selector: 'app-about',

    template: `

      <h2>About</h2>
        <a [routerLink]="['/about/item', 1]">Item 1</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/about/item', 2]">Item 2</a>
      <div class="inner-outlet">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@Routes([

  { path: '/item/:id', component: AboutItemComponent }

])

export class AboutComponent { }
```

Comment: i dont want use this way but its ok and how to bind this?i want when type on input cell params bind in a tag.

Comment: than just bind your input field value to `[(ngModel)]` and than pass that variable as routerParameter. @AlirezaValizade see my updated answer.

Comment: ` <form [ngFormModel]="model" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
                    <div>
                        <input
                                id="cell"
                                type="text"
                                name="cell"
                                ngControl="cell"


                        >
                        <label for="cell">تلفن همراه</label>
                    </div>
 </form>
  <a 
                       [routerLink]="['/SignUp' ,{ cell: model.cell }]"
                    ></a>`
i use FormBuilder and not working

Comment: try this one `<form [ngFormModel]="model" (ngSubmit)="submit()"> <div> <input id="cell" type="text" name="cell" ngControl="cell"  [(ngModel)]='cellValue'> <label for="cell">تلفن همراه</label> </div> </form> <a [routerLink]="['/SignUp' ,{ cell: cellValue }]" ></a>`

Comment: your example url will show like: `auth/signup/1654654654` not  `auth/signup?cell=1654654654` because you used  `/item/:id` in your path

Comment: hmm you are right @shaishabroy , its depends upon us how want to display url.

Answer (score 13):

You can work with `queryParams` which works with `routerLink` to *build* the `url`.  For ex:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/profiles']" 
[queryParams]="{min:45,max:50,location:29293}">
  Search
</a>
```

This will *build* a route like `http://localhost:3000/profiles?min=45&max=50&location=29923`

Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

you can try the code below:
Your ts file will be like this:

```
@Component({ ... })
@Routes([
    {
        path: '/auth/signup?cell=1654654654', component: AuthComponent
    }
])
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}
}
```

And in you html file,

```
<a [routerLink]="['//auth/signup?cell=1654654654']"></a>
```

Comment: You can bind using [(ngModel)] and use routeParams

Answer (score 2):

In Angular2 supports both query parameters and path variables within routing.

use like:

```
<a [routerLink]="['Signup', {cell: '1654654654'}]">Signup</a>
```

and in component:

```
@RouteConfig([
    new Route({ path: '/auth/signup', component: SignupComponent, name: 'Signup'})
])
```

then shown in url like that you want `/auth/signup?cell=1654654654`

NB:

If in your path contain cell in component as params like: `/auth/signup/:cell` and routelink like: `[routerLink]="['Signup', {cell: '1654654654'}]"` then url will show like: `auth/signup/1654654654`

Comment: already mentioned all your answer's content in existed  answers nothing new added to answer.

Comment: In which answer ?@PardeepJain

Comment: see my answer @Shaileshab

Comment: which answer mentioned when url shown like `auth/signup/1654654654` and when `auth/signup?cell=1654654654`. you mentioned? @PardeepJain

Comment: the question is not about how url is being shown, the question is about how to pass parameter is't it ?

Comment: also mentioned he want like: `/auth/signup?cell=1654654654` right?

Comment: but as question header suggest us `how to pass route params in [routerLink] angular 2` i think so

Comment: ok I guess he want like that that's why I shown this process :)

Comment: tnx for your answer.exactly i wanted this

Comment: you are welcome and if it helped you can accept and vote up. :) @AlirezaValizade

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is outdated and IMHO doesn't answer the question.

However the question is not clear: "route params" are in the **path** part of the URL but the question was about "query params" which are after the '?' (question mark).

So the answer to the question is in the [answer of @Akash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40500739/7458062): you have to use

```
[queryParams]="{name: value}"
```

in the template.

So this anchor will reference to `/path/with/myparam?cell=1654654654`:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/path/with/:paramName', {paramName: "myparam"}]"
   [queryParams]="{cell: 1654654654}"
></a>
```